# Why is Access-Control-Allow-Origin getting removed after I make a successful call to my API

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, api, cors, aws-api-gateway

I'm using an API set up by AWS API Gateway. I can make one successful call to this API. When I try to make another call, I get this error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'url' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

The response header has the access-control-allow-origin: * present in the first call, but it gets removed in the second call and I'm not sure why.

This is the successful API call XHR and Preflight response

Successful Preflight:

[image]

Successful XHR:

[image]

This is the failed API call XHR and Preflight response

Failed XHR:

[image]

Failed Preflight

[image]

As you can see in the failed XHR response, access-control-allow-origin is gone. I made this call very shortly after I made the first call. It doesn't make any sense to me how the first call has the origin header but the second one doesn't.

This is the ajax call I use to hit the API.

```
 $.ajax({
            url: `url`,
            method: 'GET',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            error: function (xhr) {
                if (xhr.status === 504) {
                    modelApi()
                    $('.overlayMessage').text('Server not responding, trying your search again. Please do not refresh the page')
                }
                if (xhr.status === 502) {
                    $('#overlay').fadeOut()
                    alert('No data was returned for your current search criteria. Please try selecting a different meter or date range')
                }
            }
        })
```

I also have CORS enabled on the API using the console in API Gateway. I'll post a picture of the cors config.

[image]

The docs also say that you should be sending the response to the server as well. I have that set up in the lambda function like this.

```
def get_model_lambda_handler(event,context):
    try:
        kwargs = event['params']['querystring']
        body = model.OLSRegression(**kwargs,download_data=True).run(preprocess=True)
        body = json.dumps(body,ignore_nan=True,cls=NumpyEncoder)
        response = {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'body': body,
            'headers': {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'OPTIONS,GET',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
        }
        return response
```

I think I have everything set up correctly to allow CORS. So I have no idea why I can only make one successful call. If anyone has any advice on what's going on it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just in case: I notice you're using `contentType: "application/json"` on a `GET`. It doesn't make sense to set `contentType` on a `GET`, there's no request body for the type to apply to. Perhaps AWS is being a bit pedantic?

Comment: You've mentioned two calls, one that worked and one that didn't, but shown only one bit of code. Are you saying the same code, executed twice, gives you different results? Are the endpoints the same or different? This may be obvious, but: Are they both to the same host+port using the same protocol? Perhaps you could quote the URLs you're using, with `example.com` instead of your actual host name.

Comment: Yes this code gets executed twice. One result works and the next fails. The endpoints are the same

Comment: That is **very** weird. :-)

Comment: Right?! I'm losing my mind trying to figure out what is going wrong.

Comment: I figured it out. I was only sending the response on a 200 status code. If the status code was anything else, the origin response wouldnt be included in the header.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense!! I'm glad you figured it out. Do you know, I think I've made that same mistake... Pity I didn't remember it sooner. :-) Happy coding!